# Animating control size changes dynamically

Tags: wpf, animation

I am currently working on some kind of menu which has a "flyout" mode - means it remains in compact mode (only ~60px width) until you mouse-over. The thematic is quite tricky since you can't animate the width of the control directly and setting it would cause a fixed size (which is not what I want).

My goal is to have a control which can have a dynamic size based on it's children and the max. available space in it's parent.

My theory: Once size changes, measuring will be called which measures the maximum available space (far more than will be used). The next step is *arranging*. **ArrangeOverride()** is called with a parameter *arrangeBounds* which is equivalent to the desired size.

Now I cache this value and if it's different to the *ActualSize* property, I start an animation from *ActualSize* to *arrangeBounds.Width*. The method itself does return a Size object like `return base.ArrangeOverride(new Size(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Height));`

So far I have this (and it's partially working - WidthWrapper is simply a DependencyProperty):

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
{
    if (Math.Abs(WidthWrapper) < 0.01)
        WidthWrapper = arrangeBounds.Width;

    if (Math.Abs(arrangeBounds.Width - ActualWidth) > 0.01)
    {
        if (_started & (Math.Abs(arrangeBounds.Width - _cache) < 0.01))
            return base.ArrangeOverride(new Size(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Height));
        if (Math.Abs(arrangeBounds.Width - WidthWrapper) < 0.01)
            return base.ArrangeOverride(new Size(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Height));

        if (_started & !_isExpanding)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Re-Animate");
            // Change value
            if (_cache < arrangeBounds.Width)
                _isExpanding = true;
            _cache = arrangeBounds.Width;

            _board.Stop(this);
            _board.Children.Clear();
            _anim = new DoubleAnimation(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Width,
                new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.8)))
            {
                EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase() {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut}
            };
            _board.Children.Add(_anim);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(_anim, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_anim, new PropertyPath(WidthWrapperProperty));
            _board.Begin(this);

            return base.ArrangeOverride(new Size(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Height));
        }

        if (!_started)
        {
            if (_cache < arrangeBounds.Width)
                _isExpanding = true;
            _cache = arrangeBounds.Width;
            _anim = new DoubleAnimation(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Width,
                new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)))
            {
                EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase() {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut}
            };
            _board.Children.Add(_anim);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(_anim, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_anim, new PropertyPath(WidthWrapperProperty));
            _board.Begin(this, true);
            _started = true;
        }
    }

    Size animatedSize = new Size(WidthWrapper, arrangeBounds.Height);
    return base.ArrangeOverride(animatedSize);
}
```

When starting the test project, the menu starts in almost full size and you see a part of it "fading in" from the right - which looks really cool. Now the problem is, when I switch to compact mode there's no animation. It instantly becomes ~61px wide. When I then hover over it, you see it expanding but with flickering and it randomly jumps back to the previous size.

The problem is obviously that the control is misplaced by using this approach. It seems like it shifts a bit away from the right side when doing this animation. Thus the mouse-over is not detected anymore and it tries to animate back to compact size. This happens frequently until the animation is complete and it finally reaches the full size (if it does at all).

It seems like some sort of placement-issue with it's parent. I include a GIF here, so you can see what I mean.

[image: Animation]

PS: I disabled the "flyout"-mode, but even switching from normal to compact kinda has it's issues (though it partially works and would look quite nice).

Any ideas how to solve this, to make it smoothly expand without any flickering and other issues? Professional UI libraries do have for example docking windows which do fade out quickly when unpinned. I'd like to have this kind of effect somehow applied to my menu. I assume this is possible since I've come close already - but obviously WPF does not support it without a bit of trickery.

Comment: Is there a special reason, you do this code-behind and not in XAML? Your animation looks like a simple TranslateTransform

Comment: @lokusking See my comment on Clint's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Visual State Manager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers/) and [Translate Transform](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/translatetransform/)

Essentially you'll want to describe an open and closed state, and use transforms to animate the motion between the states.

Comment: But is this independent of the desired size of the control? I mean translation would be a fixed value, wouldn't it? I can't say which size the control has either in compact or in normal mode. So this has to be flexible.

Comment: AFAIK, `From` and `To` are bindable in DoubleAnimation. And TranslateTransform's X should be bindable too

Comment: @SharpShade it's just a double animation as lokusking mentioned against the size of the control.

Comment: Okay, this is a start. But to what should I bind? I mean you can't animate Width because this would disable automatic measuring. There's actual size which can be used as starting point, but what then? I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: Didnt you define a MaxWidth? This will turn into wild guessing without seeing your ControlTemplate/Style

Comment: Nope, my goal was (like I mentioned in the initial post) to have dynamic control - one which does size to it's content. The menu is basically a ItemsControl - not much XAML here. The menu items have a lot of XAML code but I guess they don't really matter here - they're just as big as they have to be. Thus the menu should size to the widest menu item - and all size changes of the menu should be animated (width only). That's my goal ;)

Comment: There you have your answer. Simply bind it to the Actual/Desired Width of your container